# nth item of hashmap

Tags: java, algorithm, hashmap

```
HashMap selections = new HashMap<Integer, Float>();
```

How can i get the Integer key of the 3rd smaller value of Float in all HashMap?

**Edit**
im using the HashMap for this

```
for (InflatedRunner runner : prices.getRunners()) {
       for (InflatedMarketPrices.InflatedPrice price : runner.getLayPrices()) {
           if (price.getDepth() == 1) {
             selections.put(new Integer(runner.getSelectionId()), new Float(price.getPrice()));
           }
         }                    

}
```

i need the runner of the 3rd smaller  price with depth 1

maybe i should implement this in another way?

Comment: If you tell us more about what `selections` is and how you're using this query, we may be able to suggest a better data structure for you.

Comment: Can there be multiple prices with depth 1 for each runner? Because if that's possible, then your `selections` right now will only keep one of them for each `runner`.

Comment: no, just 3 depths.. 1, 2 and 3

Comment: But can a runner have its `getLayPrices` return more than 1 price at depth 1?

Comment: no no, just and always 1 of each

Comment: If it's always one of each, it makes sense to have a helper method `getLayPrice(int depth)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Michael Mrozek nails it with his question if you're using `HashMap` right: this is highly atypical scenario for `HashMap`. That said, you can do something like this:

- get the `Set<Map.Entry<K,V>>` from the `HashMap<K,V>.entrySet()`.
- `addAll` to `List<Map.Entry<K,V>>`
- `Collections.sort` the list with a custom `Comparator<Map.Entry<K,V>>` that sorts based on `V`.

  - If you just need the 3rd `Map.Entry<K,V>` only, then a `O(N)` [selection algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm) may suffice.

---

//after edit

It looks like `selection` should really be a `SortedMap<Float, InflatedRunner>`. You should look at [`java.util.TreeMap`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html).

Here's an example of how `TreeMap` can be used to get the 3rd lowest key:

```
TreeMap<Integer,String> map = new TreeMap<Integer,String>();
map.put(33, "Three");
map.put(44, "Four");
map.put(11, "One");
map.put(22, "Two");

int thirdKey = map.higherKey(map.higherKey(map.firstKey()));
System.out.println(thirdKey); // prints "33"
```

Also note how I take advantage of Java's auto-boxing/unboxing feature between `int` and `Integer`. I noticed that you used `new Integer` and `new Float` in your original code; this is unnecessary.

---

//another edit

It should be noted that if you have multiple `InflatedRunner` with the same price, only one will be kept. If this is a problem, and you want to keep all runners, then you can do one of a few things:

- If you really need a multi-map (one key can map to multiple values), then you can:

  - have `TreeMap<Float,Set<InflatedRunner>>`
  - Use `MultiMap` from [Google Collections](http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/)
- If you don't need the map functionality, then just have a `List<RunnerPricePair>` (sorry, I'm not familiar with the domain to name it appropriately), where `RunnerPricePair implements` [`Comparable<RunnerPricePair>`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) that compares on prices. You can just add all the pairs to the list, then either:

  - `Collections.sort` the list and get the 3rd pair
  - Use O(N) selection algorithm

Comment: @Daniel: I added example using `firstKey` and `higherKey`.

Comment: this works, but there is a problem.. when two equal floats are found.. and used as keys..

Comment: @Daniel: Yes, in that case only one of them will be kept. I assumed that you have some sort of bidding scheme or something, and you just need one rep for each price, and you want the 3rd lowest price, etc. I've added some more suggestions, hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure you're using hashmaps right? They're used to quickly lookup a value given a key; it's highly unusual to sort the values and then try to find a corresponding key. If anything, you should be mapping the float to the int, so you could at least sort the float keys and get the integer value of the third smallest that way

Answer (score 1):

You have to do it in steps:

1. Get the `Collection<V>` of values from the Map
2. Sort the values
3. Choose the index of the nth smallest

Think about how you want to handle ties.

Comment: If you're sorting `Collection<Float>`, how are you going to "unmap" the `Float` back to the `Integer` in the map?

Answer (score 0):

If you *regularly* need to get the key of the nth item, consider:

- using a TreeMap, which efficiently keeps keys in sorted order
- then using a double map (i.e. one TreeMap mapping integer > float, the other mapping float > integer)

You have to weigh up the inelegance and potential risk of bugs from needing to maintain two maps with the scalability benefit of having a structure that efficiently keeps the keys in order.

You may need to think about two keys mapping to the same float...

P.S. Forgot to mention: if this is an occasional function, and you just need to find the nth largest item of a large number of items, you could consider implementing a *selection* algorithm (effectively, you do a sort, but don't actually bother sorting subparts of the list that you realise you don't need to sort because their order makes no difference to the position of the item you're looking for).

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with the [google collections](http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/) [BiMap](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/index.html?http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/package-summary.html), assuming that the Floats are unique.